# Is there a standard naming convention for public values in modules?

Tags: f#

The F# code formatting guidelines give recommendations on usage of PascalCase and camelCase for the following:

`camelCase` for

- values and functions that are

  - class-bound
  - expression-bound
  - pattern-bound
  - internal and private module-bound
  - parameters
- public module-bound functions

`PascalCase` for

- module names
- type names
- type members
- discriminated union labels
- namespaces
- events
- assembly names

It does not seem to say what to do for public-bound **values** (not functions) in a module, e.g.

```ml
module MyModule = 
    let aValue = ""
```

In F# Core, there are some examples of camelCase:
`Set.empty`, `List.empty`, `Unchecked.defaultOf`

But I've seen both used in the wild.

Comment: Thank you, no I hadn't. That's interesting, basically it's use PascalCase if it'll be .NET-facing, otherwise you can use either.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *either* camelCase or PascalCase for public values in modules.

From p. 7 of the [F# Component Design Guidelines](https://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/fsharp-design-guidelines-v14.pdf) (or [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/component-design-guidelines#use-either-pascalcase-or-camelcase-for-public-functions-and-values-in-f-modules)):

> Do use either PascalCase or camelCase for public functions and values in F# modules.